# filter array of list into sub array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am stuck at code, i have a array of  li's element and i want another array which contains  li from ist array which has classname hide. here is what i am trying

```
<div id="videoarea ">
  <ul>
    <li class="hide">a</li>
    <li class="hide">a</li>
    <li class="hide">a</li>
    <li >a</li>
    <li >a</li>
    <li >a</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="hide">b</li>
    <li class="hide">b</li>
    <li class="hide">b</li>
    <li >b</li>
    <li >b</li>
    <li >b</li>
  </ul>
</div>
var items = $("#videoarea div ul");

var templi = items.eq(1).children().hasClass("hide"); // it is only showing true, i want array of li's having class hide
```

I want an array which contains li's of particular ul having class hide and if possible another array which dont have class hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `li` elements with `.hide`, simply connect them in a selector.

For `li` elements without `.hide`, use [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
var items = $("#videoarea div ul");

var liWithHide = items.eq(1).children("li.hide"); 
var liWithoutHide = items.eq(1).children("li:not(.hide)");
```